# Queries to be tested in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Why I can't get any results with this queries? What I'm doing wrong here?

QUERY 1

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:PRS_knows_PRS*1..2]-(friend:Person),
    (friend)<-[:CMT_hasCreator_PRS]-(friendPost:Post)-[:PST_hasTag_TAG]->(knownTag:Tag {nameTag:2})
WHERE not(person=friend)
MATCH (friendPost)-[:PST_hasTag_TAG]->(commonTag:Tag)
WHERE not(commonTag=knownTag)
WITH DISTINCT commonTag, knownTag, friend
MATCH (commonTag)<-[:PST_hasTag_TAG]-(commonPost:Post)-[:PST_hasTag_TAG]->(knownTag)
WHERE (commonPost)-[:CMT_hasCreator_PRS]->(friend)
RETURN
    commonTag.nameTag AS tagName,
    count(commonPost) AS postCount
ORDER BY postCount DESC, tagName ASC
LIMIT 3
```

QUERY 2

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:PRS_knows_PRS*1..2]-(friend:Person)
WHERE not(person=friend)
WITH DISTINCT friend
MATCH (friend)-[worksAt:PRS_worksAt_ORG]->(company:Organisation)-[:ORG_isLocatedIn_PLC]->(:Country {name:{3}})
WHERE worksAt.workFromPWAO < {2}
RETURN
    friend.idPerson AS friendId,
    friend.firstNamePerson AS friendFirstName,
    friend.lastNamePerson AS friendLastName,
    worksAt.workFromPWAO AS workFromYear,
    company.nameOrganisation AS companyName
ORDER BY workFromYear ASC, friendId ASC, companyName DESC
LIMIT 4
```

I have this nodes, property Keys and relatioship types:
[image: Nodes - Property Keys - Relationship Types]

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Could you explain in plain English what this query is trying to accomplish?  When you execute it, what do you get?   What do you expect to get? What's the difference?

Comment: These 2 queries are for testing Neo4j. They are created by the Social Network Benchmark for testing in terms of performance/time the results given by Neo4j. When I'm executing this 2 queries I get  no results. The expected result should be a certain info delivered by the Return clause, and the problem is in here. These 2 queries don't deliver any results and I don't understand why...

Comment: Does it say that there are no returned values? Or is there an error? And your response to @FrobberOfBits does not help at all. If someone doesn't already know that you are doing this query to return some value, then i really don't believe they can help you. Try telling us what is the data, not just some data, but exactly what data you are looking for.

Comment: The message that appears to me after executing the query is:
(no rows)

So, no returned values.
The data in here is a graph database generated in SNB, loaded to Neo4j via .csv files. Something similar to a social network database, as you can see on the image that I uploaded - the nodes/property keys/relatioship types that I got on the graph database.
These queries are to test Neo4j performance - they are written in the SNB manual (with some modifications according to my graph database)
These queries should return some info and the time of execution - and nothing of this appears...

Comment: If it says that there are no values, well then nothing matches your query, hence there are no values. If you are sure a value which matches your query, exists, then there is something wrong with the query logic. To identify that error, we will need to know what data you are looking for. Eg: I want to find all Persons which are friends of friends and liked a certain picture. In that case, we could write you a query and you could compare. But unless you can tell us that, there is no way to identify your problem

Comment: It would be great if you could share a demo database, e.g. on console.neo4j.org so that we could try to run your queries there.

Answer (score 1):

On your query you use this relationship name:

> worksAt:PRS_worksAt_ORG

but on your screen shot of the properties the relationship is called 'PRS_workAt_ORG' without the 's' on workAt.

Maybe that's what's missing on the second query?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it helps to build up the queries step by step.

Then you see where they stop returning data.

A PROFILE (prefix) of your queries should also help to see where it starts to return ZERO rows.

Could also be a case-typo in one of the labels and rel-types.